# Error while installing Unity Tweak Tool through Terminal (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: command-line, unity, unity-tweak-tool, tweak

When I enter `sudo apt-get install unity tweak` I get this message:

```
***Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)***
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool `

Comment: wow surprisingly it works! thanks alot m8, you should post it as an answer

Comment: Ok, will do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just typing it wrong it should be:

```
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
```

Sure you would agree that the system is telling you something isn't right is a good thing, sadly it doesn't really do that in a satisfactory way.

To prevent future mishaps like this you can simply use `apt-cache search` to get the proper package name.

Example:

```
apt-cache search unity-tweak
```

will result in this:

```
$ apt-cache search unity-tweak
unity-tweak-tool - configuration tool for the Unity desktop environment
```

Comment: yep funny how such small mistakes can prevent an entire commnd. thnks man